# How to turn off shapes in YIntervalRenderer?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Found no way t turn off shapes accessing renderer itself.

```
renderer.setSeriesShape(0, null);
```

disables series shape, but causes shapes from supplier come.

```
renderer.setAutoPopulateSeriesShape(false);
```

disables supplier, but causes default shape draw.

```
renderer.setBaseShape(null);
```

causes exception since null is not allowed here as a parameter.

So where to turn shapes off? May be in plot or chart object? Can't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply an empty `Shape` for any series:

```
YIntervalRenderer r = new YIntervalRenderer();
r.setSeriesShape(0, new Rectangle());
```

Comment: No problem; if you have many series, you can override `getItemShape()` in `AbstractRenderer`.

Comment: It took me way to long to realize this wasn't working because I was already using org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle for something else but needed java.awt.Rectangle for this.

Comment: @user2020056: Ouch! Glad you got it sorted. I've added a link to the relevant interface.